# How can I find database storage format specifications without wading through source code?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm writing my own database for my resume and out of frustration with all the complexities of other databases (mine has 4 operations only: push, pull, drop, and find ). It's a key-value store which hashes the key and then generates a folder tree to store a file in.

Let's say I push {"Bob": {"password":"Duck"}} to my database. Let's say the SHA hash for Bob is: AABBCCDD

Bob is stored in file DD in the AA/BB/CC/ directory.

I did this so that constantly accessing database files wouldn't corrupt the entire database. Problem is, I'm worried about speed now.

I'd like to review the storage techniques of other databases but can't really find their specifications. All I can find are advantages of their database like MongoDB which compresses data and stores it in BSON. Whenever I search Google for the specifications, that's what usually comes up.

Is there something I can actually read -- besides source code -- which tells how data is saved to the hard drive in a database?

Answer (score 1):

For SQLite, the only RDBMs that you've tagged then the database file format can be found here [Database File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html)

There's a bit about file access here that may be of interest [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) and also here [Write-Ahead Logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)

But when it boils down to it there are many factors that can effect performance apart from just how files are written to, for example the underlying file system, the storage devices, indexing, cacheing (perhaps see [PRAGMA Statements](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html)), use of transactions, query optimisation [The SQLite Query Optimizer Overview](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html) and [Query Planning](https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html)